# JAVA: Replacing words in string

Tags: java, string, replace, words

I want to replace words in a string, but I am having little difficulties. Here is what I want to do. I have string:

```
String a = "I want to replace some words in this string";
```

It should work like some kind of a translator. I am doing this with `String.replaceAll()`, but it doesn't work completely because of this. Let's say I am translating from English to German, than this should be the output (`Ich` means `I` in German).

```
String toTranslate = "I";
String translated = "Ich";
a = a.replaceAll(toTranslate.toLowerCase(), translated.toLowerCase());
```

Now the output of the String `a` will be this:

```
"ich want to replace some words ich**n** **th**ich**s** **str**ich**ng**"
```

How to replace just the words, not the subwords in the words?

Comment: use Regex's groups `()`.

Comment: Can't you assume `I` will always be captialized in english, then in your code just remove both `.toLowerCase()` and it should work

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll` uses regex, so you may add [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) or [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms to check if there are no non-space characters surrounding word you want to replace.

```
String toTranslate = "I";
String translated = "Ich";
a = a.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)"+toTranslate.toLowerCase()+"(?!\\S)", translated.toLowerCase());
```

You can also add quotation mechanism to escape any regex metacharacters like `+` `*` `(` inside word you want to replace. BTW you don't need to change your string to lower case, simply add case-insensitive flag to regex `(?i)`.

```
a = a.replaceAll("(?i)(?<!\\S)"+Pattern.quote(toTranslate)+"(?!\\S)", translated.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split(" ")` for getting each word in the sentence. And then use replaceAll on each word.

```
  String a = "I want to replace some words in this string";
        String toTranslate = "I";
        String translated = "Ich";
        String newString[]=a.split(" ");
        for (String string : newString) {
            string=string.replaceAll(toTranslate, toTranslate.toLowerCase());//Adding this line ensures you dont miss any uppercase toTranslate
            string=string.replaceAll(toTranslate.toLowerCase(), translated.toLowerCase());
            System.out.println("after translation ="+string);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String toTranslate = "I ";
String translated = "Ich ";
a = a.replaceAll(toTranslate.toLowerCase(), translated.toLowerCase());
```

If you add a space after the "I" it should replace it when it comes to the word "Ich" but if your word ends in a "I" then thats another problem

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that `I` will always be capitalized in English as it should be then

```
a = a.replaceAll(toTranslate, translated);
```

will work, otherwise you need to replace both cases

```
a = a.replaceAll(toTranslate, translated);
a = a.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z])("+toTranslate.toLowerCase()+")([^a-zA-Z])", "$1"+translated.toLowerCase()+"$3");
```

Here is a working [example](http://goo.gl/AKCzyu)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the word boundaries are the solution. I just did this in the regex:

```
text.replaceAll("\\b" + parts1[i] + "\\b", map.element.value);
```

Don't be confused with the second argument it's string (from Hash table).

Answer (score -1):

You can use RegEx's word bound, which is \b

```
String toTranslate = "\\bI\\b";
String translated = "Ich";
a = a.replaceAll(toTranslate.toLowerCase(), translated.toLowerCase());
```

This should ensure I is separated entirely into its own word

Edit: I misread the question and realized you want whole words. See above, as I have accounted for that